# SQLite or SQL Server CE for Entity Framework migrations?

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, sql-server-ce, entity-framework-migrations

I'm starting a project and I will need to use the migrations provided by Entity Framework 6.

I found that SQLite does not have support for migrations.

SQL Server CE is the better option if I need to use the code-first migrations, or do I have other choices?

Remembering, I need a self-contained database engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No other choices, as far as I know

Comment: You know if SQLCE is deprecated?

Comment: Support lifecycle: http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/default.aspx?sort=PN&alpha=Microsoft+SQL+Server+Compact&Filter=FilterNO